# Como reutilizar esse js em outros elementos

Tags: javascript, funções

Não tenho muito conhecimento em JS, mas consegui essa função que faz exatamente o que preciso, porem quando duplico a div html que utiliza desta mesma função js ela não funciona, eu havia visto em algum lugar que o documento executa a primeira vez e não permite reutilizar a função, alguém poderia me ajudar com isso? Abraço.

```
 <script>


   var c = document.getElementById("btn");

    c.addEventListener('click',function(){
      var elemento = document.getElementById("section3");
      if(elemento.style.height !== '100%')
          elemento.style.height = '100%', elemento.style.transition = '.5s';
      else
          elemento.style.height = '90px';
    });


</script>
```

Comment: Quando duplicas ela fica com esse mesmo id? `section3`?

Answer (score 2):

Você está associando uma function anônima para o evento click do elemento com id `btn`. **O id <s>é</s> deve ser um elemento único na página**, não pode existir dois ou mais elementos com IDs iguais, senão as coisas começam a bugar.
Por tanto no seu caso, seria ideal você vincular a function através do attributo `class`, pois este pode repetir avontade.

#### Solução

Altere os elementos com os IDs `btn` e `section3` para usar isso como classe. Você pode **remover** esses IDs ou apenas **adicionar** `class` com o mesmo valor do `id`.

Após isso, altere seu código para usar `getElementsByClassName` ao invés de `getElementById`. Atenção: `getElementsByClassName` pode encontrar mais de um elemento, por isso ele sempre vai retornar uma coleção, dê uma olhadinha na [documentação](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementsbyclassname.asp).

Comment: Nossa muito obrigado, não havia me ligado nisso kk vlw

Comment: Olá, eu fiz como vc falou, porem a ação não funciona mais, tenteu incluir uma class com o mesmo nome dos Ids e inclui o getElementsByClassName porem não faz mais nada?                                                  var c = document.getElementsByClassName("btn");

    c.addEventListener('click',function(){
        var elemento = document.getElementsByClassName("section3");
        if(elemento.style.height !== '100%')
            elemento.style.height = '100%', elemento.style.transition = '.5s';
        else
            elemento.style.height = '90px';
    });

Comment: @HudsonVicentim é porque getElementsByClassName retorna uma lista, então vc precisa dar loop. É diferente do getElementById que só retornava um único elemento.

Answer (score 0):

Tu pode adicionar um handler de evento em todos os botões onde o handler alterna uma classe que dá visibilidade para tua sessão.

Segue um exemplo:

```js
var btns = document.querySelectorAll('.toggle'),
    i, l;

function click_listener() {
  this.parentElement.classList.toggle('show');
}

for(i=0, l=btns.length ; i<l ; i++){
  btns[i].addEventListener('click', click_listener);
}
```

```css
.teste {
  border: #ccc solid 1px;
  padding: 8px;
  height: 90px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.teste.show {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<section class="teste">
  <button class="toggle" type="button">Click me</button>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque aliquam iaculis accumsan. Mauris id orci at est blandit auctor sed efficitur diam. Mauris maximus purus quis congue eleifend. Sed sit amet tellus lacinia, vulputate purus tempor, posuere mi. Vivamus consectetur, velit quis porta faucibus, metus nulla ullamcorper lorem, eget ullamcorper quam nisl non risus. Cras sodales nisi in blandit tempor. Sed eleifend turpis vitae justo maximus ornare. Integer ornare, erat at gravida vestibulum, ante enim ullamcorper neque, quis tincidunt est arcu et velit. Donec ut nisl non nibh dignissim bibendum. Etiam convallis metus sem. Aenean id aliquet orci. Nam sed nisi augue.</p>

  <p>Vestibulum vel ultrices nulla. Donec malesuada ex mauris, sit amet aliquet ante egestas ut. Aliquam mollis pharetra leo, eu lacinia turpis dignissim posuere. Ut arcu orci, ultrices id lectus vel, pellentesque semper nunc. Donec in sodales turpis. Aenean quis nunc vel tellus porta maximus quis non quam. Integer accumsan turpis arcu, iaculis facilisis diam luctus eu.</p>
</section>
<section class="teste">
  <button class="toggle" type="button">Click me</button>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque aliquam iaculis accumsan. Mauris id orci at est blandit auctor sed efficitur diam. Mauris maximus purus quis congue eleifend. Sed sit amet tellus lacinia, vulputate purus tempor, posuere mi. Vivamus consectetur, velit quis porta faucibus, metus nulla ullamcorper lorem, eget ullamcorper quam nisl non risus. Cras sodales nisi in blandit tempor. Sed eleifend turpis vitae justo maximus ornare. Integer ornare, erat at gravida vestibulum, ante enim ullamcorper neque, quis tincidunt est arcu et velit. Donec ut nisl non nibh dignissim bibendum. Etiam convallis metus sem. Aenean id aliquet orci. Nam sed nisi augue.</p>

  <p>Vestibulum vel ultrices nulla. Donec malesuada ex mauris, sit amet aliquet ante egestas ut. Aliquam mollis pharetra leo, eu lacinia turpis dignissim posuere. Ut arcu orci, ultrices id lectus vel, pellentesque semper nunc. Donec in sodales turpis. Aenean quis nunc vel tellus porta maximus quis non quam. Integer accumsan turpis arcu, iaculis facilisis diam luctus eu.</p>
</section>
<section class="teste">
  <button class="toggle" type="button">Click me</button>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque aliquam iaculis accumsan. Mauris id orci at est blandit auctor sed efficitur diam. Mauris maximus purus quis congue eleifend. Sed sit amet tellus lacinia, vulputate purus tempor, posuere mi. Vivamus consectetur, velit quis porta faucibus, metus nulla ullamcorper lorem, eget ullamcorper quam nisl non risus. Cras sodales nisi in blandit tempor. Sed eleifend turpis vitae justo maximus ornare. Integer ornare, erat at gravida vestibulum, ante enim ullamcorper neque, quis tincidunt est arcu et velit. Donec ut nisl non nibh dignissim bibendum. Etiam convallis metus sem. Aenean id aliquet orci. Nam sed nisi augue.</p>

  <p>Vestibulum vel ultrices nulla. Donec malesuada ex mauris, sit amet aliquet ante egestas ut. Aliquam mollis pharetra leo, eu lacinia turpis dignissim posuere. Ut arcu orci, ultrices id lectus vel, pellentesque semper nunc. Donec in sodales turpis. Aenean quis nunc vel tellus porta maximus quis non quam. Integer accumsan turpis arcu, iaculis facilisis diam luctus eu.</p>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Não sei se entendi direito o que você queria mas você poderia utilizar prototype em javascript pra poder fazer componentes reutilizáveis. Dei um pontapé inicial com um componente bem simples, mas nada impede de você melhorar ele pra que seja da forma que você quer.
Veja se é isso que você precisa, se não for, seja mais específico que posso ajudar melhor.
http://codepen.io/netonneettoo/pen/MJopwd